# How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I have open the Google Play store using the following code

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my packagename "));
startActivity(i);.
```

But it shows me a Complete Action View as to select the option (browser/play store). I need to open the application in Play Store directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Rate This App"-link in Google Play store app on the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816757/rate-this-app-link-in-google-play-store-app-on-the-phone)

Answer (score 1687, accepted):

You can do this using the [`market://` prefix](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html).

### Java

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

### Kotlin

```
try {
    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName")))
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageName")))
}
```

We use a `try/catch` block here because an `Exception` will be thrown if the Play Store is not installed on the target device.

**NOTE**: Any app can register as capable of handling the `market://details?id=<appId>` URI. If you want to specifically target Google Play, the solution in [*Berťák*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090925/1438733) is a good alternative.

Comment: I have tried already with this code, this is also shows the option to select the browser/play store, because my device have installed both apps(google play store/browser).

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. I use this code on both 2.3.3 and 4.1 and both open up the Play Store. Additionally, [the docs](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#android-app) say `market://` "*Launches the Play Store app*".

Comment: if you want to redirect to all Developer's apps use `market://search?q=pub:"+devName` and `http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:"+devName`

Comment: thank u for the post. Me also tried with this code but it shows the option to select the browser/playstore. rajesh if u got the answer for this issue means update the post.

Comment: For how to open google play independently (not embedded in a new view in the same app) please check my answer.

Comment: What if I want to open Play with a 'referrer' param? Am I expected to simply add it to the URI, e.g. "market://xxxxx&referrer=abc" ? Or do I need to update some other part of the Intent/action/etc?

Comment: @SagiMann-TROPHiT Honestly, I'm not sure. You'd be better off starting a new question.

Comment: Doesn't the web link need https now?

Comment: @ooolala Need, no. Should have, yes. Will change that.

Comment: Can I return to my app after the download is finish? Thanks.

Comment: @offset No, unfortunately not. There might be an `Intent` you could capture on package addition, but even then I don't think the OS provides you the control to switch over to your app. (Just to do something in the background.)

Comment: This solution does not work, if some application uses intent filter with "market://" scheme defined. See my answer how to open Google Play AND ONLY Google Play application (or webbrowser if GP not present). :-)

Comment: For projects using the Gradle build system, `appPackageName` is in fact `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`. No `Context`/`Activity` dependencies, reducing the risk of memory leaks.

Comment: You still need the context to launch the intent. Context.startActivity()

Comment: This solution assumes there is an intent to open a web browser.  This isn't always true (like on Android TV) so be cautious.  You may want to use intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) to determine what to do.

Comment: Developer is now:
From a website: http://play.google.com/store/dev?id=<developer_id>
From an Android app: market://dev?id=<developer_id>

Comment: market:// is not working if i am redirecting from another domain url. For example if user is opening url https://www.example.com/blabla in his browser and i am simply redirecting to market://details?id=com.example.blabla previously its working but from 1 week onwards its not working. can anyone help me regarding this. i am using nodejs for URL redirection.

Comment: @DhavalRajani It wouldn't work on my emulator but on real hardware for me.

Comment: I think you should use application id instead of package name.

Answer (score 189):

**Many answers here suggest to use** `Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName))` **to open Google Play, but I think it is insufficient** in fact:

**Some third-party applications can use its own intent-filters with `"market://"` scheme defined**, thus they can process supplied Uri instead of Google Play (I experienced this situation with e.g.SnapPea application). The question is "How to open the Google Play Store?", so I assume, that you do not want to open any other application. Please also note, that e.g. app rating is only relevant in GP Store app etc...

**To open Google Play AND ONLY Google Play I use this method:**

```
public static void openAppRating(Context context) {
    // you can also use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
    String appId = context.getPackageName();
    Intent rateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appId));
    boolean marketFound = false;

    // find all applications able to handle our rateIntent
    final List<ResolveInfo> otherApps = context.getPackageManager()
        .queryIntentActivities(rateIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo otherApp: otherApps) {
        // look for Google Play application
        if (otherApp.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName
                .equals("com.android.vending")) {

            ActivityInfo otherAppActivity = otherApp.activityInfo;
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                    otherAppActivity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                    otherAppActivity.name
                    );
            // make sure it does NOT open in the stack of your activity
            rateIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // task reparenting if needed
            rateIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            // if the Google Play was already open in a search result
            //  this make sure it still go to the app page you requested
            rateIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            // this make sure only the Google Play app is allowed to
            // intercept the intent
            rateIntent.setComponent(componentName);
            context.startActivity(rateIntent);
            marketFound = true;
            break;

        }
    }

    // if GP not present on device, open web browser
    if (!marketFound) {
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+appId));
        context.startActivity(webIntent);
    }
}
```

The point is that when more applications beside Google Play can open our intent, app-chooser dialog is skipped and GP app is started directly.

**UPDATE:** 
Sometimes it seems that it opens GP app only, without opening the app's profile. As TrevorWiley suggested in his comment, `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` could fix the problem. (I didn't test it myself yet...)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376250) for understanding what `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` does.

Comment: While this is good it also seems unreliable with the current Google Play build, if you enter another apps page on Google Play then trigger this code, it will just open Google Play but not go to your app.

Comment: @zoltish, I've added Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to the flags and that seems to fix the problem

Comment: I have used Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED but not work. no any new Instance open of Play store

Comment: What happens if you use `rateIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending")` to be sure the PlayStore app gonna handle this intent, Instead of all this code?

Comment: @dum4ll3 I guess you can but this code also implicitly check if the Google Play app is installed. If you do not check it you need to catch for ActivityNotFound

Comment: You can use `getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending")` instead of the first `for` `if`.

Comment: I'm using this solution in Kotlin. Opening the app page in PlayStore works, but starting webIntent crashes the app. Not sure if it's correct solution, but it can be fixed by adding `webIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` before `context.startActivity(webIntent)`

Answer (score 102):

Go on Android Developer official link as tutorial step by step see and got the code for your application package from play store if exists or play store apps not exists then open application from web browser.

**Android Developer official link**

https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html

**Linking to a Application Page**

From a web site: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>`

From an Android app: `market://details?id=<package_name>`

**Linking to a Product List**

From a web site: `https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:<publisher_name>`

From an Android app: `market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>`

**Linking to a Search Result**

From a web site: `https://play.google.com/store/search?q=<search_query>&c=apps`

From an Android app: `market://search?q=<seach_query>&c=apps`

Comment: Using market:// prefix is not recommended anymore (check the link you posted)

Comment: @GregEnnis where you see that market:// prefix is not recommended anymore ?

Comment: @loki I think the point is that it's not listed as a suggestion any more. If you search that page for the word `market` you won't find any solution. I think the new way is to fire off a more generic intent https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app . More recent versions of the Play Store app probably have an intent filter for this URI `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android`

Answer (score 34):

While Eric's answer is correct and Berťák's code also works. I think this combines both more elegantly.

```
try {
    Intent appStoreIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
    appStoreIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");

    startActivity(appStoreIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException exception) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

By using `setPackage`, you force the device to use the Play Store. If there is no Play Store installed, the `Exception` will be caught.

Comment: The official docs use `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` instead of `market:` How come? https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app Still a comprehensive and short answer.

Comment: I tried Berťák's code and it works but this one is much simpler.

Answer (score 27):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: For how to open google play independently (not embedded in a new view in the same app) please check my answer.

Answer (score 24):

**All of the above answers open Google Play in a new view of the same app, if you actually want to open Google Play (or any other app) independently:**

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");

// package name and activity
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.vending",
                                       "com.google.android.finsky.activities.LaunchUrlHandlerActivity"); 
launchIntent.setComponent(comp);

// sample to open facebook app
launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.facebook.katana"));
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

**The important part is that actually opens google play or any other app independently.**

Most of what I have seen uses the approach of the other answers and it was not what I needed hopefully this helps somebody.

Regards.

Comment: What is `this.cordova`? Where are the variable declarations? Where is `callback` declared and defined?

Comment: this is part of a Cordova plugin, I don't think that is actually relevant ... you just need an instance of PackageManager and start an activity in a regular way but this is the cordova plugin of https://github.com/lampaa which I overwrote here https://github.com/code4jhon/org.apache.cordova.startapp

Comment: My point is simply that, this code isn't really something that people can simply port to their own app for use. Trimming the fat and leaving just the core method would be useful to future readers.

Comment: Yes, I understand ... for now I am on hybrid apps. Can't really test completely native code. But I think the idea is there. If I have a chance I will add exact native lines.

Comment: hopefully this will make it @eric

Answer (score 16):

You can check if the *Google Play Store* app is installed and, if this is the case, you can use the *"market://"* protocol.

```
final String my_package_name = "........."  // <- HERE YOUR PACKAGE NAME!!
String url = "";

try {
    //Check whether Google Play store is installed or not:
    this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.android.vending", 0);

    url = "market://details?id=" + my_package_name;
} catch ( final Exception e ) {
    url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + my_package_name;
}


//Open the app page in Google Play store:
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: For how to open google play independently (not embedded in a new view in the same app) please check my answer.

Answer (score 13):

use market://

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + my_packagename));
```

Answer (score 11):

As [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app) use `https://` instead of `market://`, this combines Eric's and M3-n50's answer with code reuse (don't repeat yourself):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(intent)
                  .setPackage("com.android.vending"));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException exception) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It tries to open with the GPlay app if it exists and falls back to default.

Answer (score 11):

Some of the answers to this question are outdated.

What worked for me (in 2020) was to explicitly tell the intent to skip the chooser and directly open the play store app, according to [this link](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app):

> "If you want to link to your products from an Android app, create an
> Intent that opens a URL. As you configure this intent, pass
> "com.android.vending" into Intent.setPackage() so that users see your
> app's details in the Google Play Store app instead of a chooser."

This is the Kotlin code I used to direct users to viewing the app containing the package name com.google.android.apps.maps in Google Play:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
               data = Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps")
               setPackage("com.android.vending")
            }
            startActivity(intent)
```

I hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 9):

Kotlin:

Extension:

```
fun Activity.openAppInGooglePlay(){

val appId = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
try {
    this.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$appId")))
} catch (anfe: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    this.startActivity(
        Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appId")
        )
    )
}}
```

Method:

```
    fun openAppInGooglePlay(activity:Activity){

        val appId = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
        try {
            activity.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$appId")))
        } catch (anfe: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            activity.startActivity(
                Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appId")
                )
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
final Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri));
```

get Reference [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html):

You can also try the approach described in the accepted answer of this question:
[Cannot determine whether Google play store is installed or not on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551531/cannot-determine-whether-google-play-store-is-installed-or-not-on-android-device)

Comment: I have tried already with this code, this is also shows the option to select the browser/play store, because my device have installed both apps(google play store/browser).

Comment: For how to open google play independently (not embedded in a new view in the same app) please check my answer.

Answer (score 8):

#### Kotlin

```
fun openAppInPlayStore(appPackageName: String) {
    try {
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$appPackageName")))
    } catch (exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException) {
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName")))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Very late in the party [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app) are here. And code described is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(
    "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android"));
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(intent);
```

As you configure this intent, pass `"com.android.vending"` into `Intent.setPackage()` so that users see your app's details in the ***Google Play Store app* instead of a chooser**.
for KOTLIN

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    data = Uri.parse(
            "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android")
    setPackage("com.android.vending")
}
startActivity(intent)
```

If you have published an instant app using Google Play Instant, you can launch the app as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details")
    .buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter("id", "com.example.android")
    .appendQueryParameter("launch", "true");

// Optional parameters, such as referrer, are passed onto the launched
// instant app. You can retrieve these parameters using
// Activity.getIntent().getData().
uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("referrer", "exampleCampaignId");

intent.setData(uriBuilder.build());
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(intent);
```

For KOTLIN

```
val uriBuilder = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details")
        .buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("id", "com.example.android")
        .appendQueryParameter("launch", "true")

// Optional parameters, such as referrer, are passed onto the launched
// instant app. You can retrieve these parameters using Activity.intent.data.
uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("referrer", "exampleCampaignId")

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    data = uriBuilder.build()
    setPackage("com.android.vending")
}
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: I think, this is wrong, at least, `Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=`. On some devices it opens web-browser instead of Play Market.

Comment: All the code is taken from official docs. Link is also attached in answer code is described here for a quick reference.

Comment: @CoolMind the reason for that is probably because those devices have an older version of Play Store app which don't have an intent filter matching that URI.

Comment: @tir38, maybe so. Maybe they don't have Google Play Services or not authorized in them, I don't remember.

Answer (score 7):

Ready-to-use solution:

```
public class GoogleServicesUtils {

    public static void openAppInGooglePlay(Context context) {
        final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
        try {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) { // if there is no Google Play on device
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        }
    }

}
```

Based on Eric's answer.

Comment: Does it work for you? It opens the main Google Play page, not my app's page.

Answer (score 6):

This link will open the app automatically in `market://` if you are on Android and in browser if you are on PC.

```
https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.id&ddl=1&pcampaignid=web_ddl_1
```

Comment: Actually in my task, there is an webview and in webview I have to load any URL. but in that if there is open any playstore url it shows open playstore  button.
so I need to open app on click of that button. it will be dynamic for any application, so how can I manage?

Comment: Just try the link ```https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.id&ddl=1&pcampaignid=web_ddl_1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to open Google Play store from your app then use this command directy: `market://details?gotohome=com.yourAppName`, it will open your app's Google Play store pages.

- Web: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=
- App: market://details?id=

Show all apps by a specific publisher

- Web: http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:
- App: market://search?q=pub:

Search for apps that using the Query on its title or description

- Web: http://play.google.com/store/search?q=
- App: market://search?q=

Reference: https://tricklio.com/market-details-gotohome-1/

Comment: This seems to no longer work unfortunately.  It crashes in an android app & gives a promise exception in iOS (expected but worth testing)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the final code from the answers above that first attempts to open the app using the Google play store app and specifically play store, if it fails, it will start the action view using the web version:
Credits to @Eric, @Jonathan Caballero

```
public void goToPlayStore() {
        String playStoreMarketUrl = "market://details?id=";
        String playStoreWebUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
        String packageName = getActivity().getPackageName();
        try {
            Intent intent =  getActivity()
                            .getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");
            if (intent != null) {
                ComponentName androidComponent = new ComponentName("com.android.vending",
                        "com.google.android.finsky.activities.LaunchUrlHandlerActivity");
                intent.setComponent(androidComponent);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(playStoreMarketUrl + packageName));
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(playStoreMarketUrl + packageName));
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(playStoreWebUrl + packageName));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have combined both *Berťák* and  *Stefano Munarini* answer to creating a hybrid solution which handles both **Rate this App** and **Show More App** scenario.

```
        /**
         * This method checks if GooglePlay is installed or not on the device and accordingly handle
         * Intents to view for rate App or Publisher's Profile
         *
         * @param showPublisherProfile pass true if you want to open Publisher Page else pass false to open APp page
         * @param publisherID          pass Dev ID if you have passed PublisherProfile true
         */
        public void openPlayStore(boolean showPublisherProfile, String publisherID) {

            //Error Handling
            if (publisherID == null || !publisherID.isEmpty()) {
                publisherID = "";
                //Log and continue
                Log.w("openPlayStore Method", "publisherID is invalid");
            }

            Intent openPlayStoreIntent;
            boolean isGooglePlayInstalled = false;

            if (showPublisherProfile) {
                //Open Publishers Profile on PlayStore
                openPlayStoreIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:" + publisherID));
            } else {
                //Open this App on PlayStore
                openPlayStoreIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName()));
            }

            // find all applications who can handle openPlayStoreIntent
            final List<ResolveInfo> otherApps = getPackageManager()
                    .queryIntentActivities(openPlayStoreIntent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo otherApp : otherApps) {

                // look for Google Play application
                if (otherApp.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.equals("com.android.vending")) {

                    ActivityInfo otherAppActivity = otherApp.activityInfo;
                    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                            otherAppActivity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                            otherAppActivity.name
                    );
                    // make sure it does NOT open in the stack of your activity
                    openPlayStoreIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    // task reparenting if needed
                    openPlayStoreIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                    // if the Google Play was already open in a search result
                    //  this make sure it still go to the app page you requested
                    openPlayStoreIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    // this make sure only the Google Play app is allowed to
                    // intercept the intent
                    openPlayStoreIntent.setComponent(componentName);
                    startActivity(openPlayStoreIntent);
                    isGooglePlayInstalled = true;
                    break;

                }
            }
            // if Google Play is not Installed on the device, open web browser
            if (!isGooglePlayInstalled) {

                Intent webIntent;
                if (showPublisherProfile) {
                    //Open Publishers Profile on web browser
                    webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:" + getPackageName()));
                } else {
                    //Open this App on web browser
                    webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
                }
                startActivity(webIntent);
            }
        }
```

**Usage**

- To Open Publishers Profile

> ```
>    @OnClick(R.id.ll_more_apps)
>         public void showMoreApps() {
>             openPlayStore(true, "Hitesh Sahu");
>         }
> ```

- To Open App Page on PlayStore

> ```
> @OnClick(R.id.ll_rate_this_app)
> public void openAppInPlayStore() {
>     openPlayStore(false, "");
> }
> ```

Comment: Id suggest divide this code into smaller methods. It's hard to find important code in this spaghetti :) Plus you're checking for  _"com.android.vending"_ what about _com.google.market_

Answer (score 3):

```
public void launchPlayStore(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = null;
    try {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

My kotlin entension function for this purpose

```
fun Context.canPerformIntent(intent: Intent): Boolean {
        val mgr = this.packageManager
        val list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
        return list.size > 0
    }
```

And in your activity

```
val uri = if (canPerformIntent(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://")))) {
            Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)
        } else {
            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)
        }
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri))
```

Answer (score 3):

**KOTLIN :**
create extension in context.

```
fun Context.openPlayStoreApp(pkgName:String?){
    if(!pkgName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        try {
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$pkgName")))
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            startActivity(
                Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$pkgName")
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Peoples, dont forget that you could actually get something more from it. I mean UTM tracking for example. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

```
public static final String MODULE_ICON_PACK_FREE = "com.example.iconpack_free";
public static final String APP_STORE_URI =
        "market://details?id=%s&referrer=utm_source=%s&utm_medium=app&utm_campaign=plugin";
public static final String APP_STORE_GENERIC_URI =
        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%s&referrer=utm_source=%s&utm_medium=app&utm_campaign=plugin";

try {
    startActivity(new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse(String.format(Locale.US,
            APP_STORE_URI,
            MODULE_ICON_PACK_FREE,
            getPackageName()))).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse(String.format(Locale.US,
            APP_STORE_GENERIC_URI,
            MODULE_ICON_PACK_FREE,
            getPackageName()))).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A kotlin verison with fallback and current syntax

```
 fun openAppInPlayStore() {
    val uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.packageName)
    val goToMarketIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)

    var flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    flags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        flags or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT
    } else {
        flags or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }

    goToMarketIntent.addFlags(flags)

    try {
        startActivity(context, goToMarketIntent, null)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.packageName))

        startActivity(context, intent, null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To open Google Play Store app instead of chooser use below method, If app is not installed in Google Play Store it will go to catch block and open chooser.

Try below,

```
public static void launchPlayStore(Activity activity, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = null;
    try {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rate Application: Redirect to Playstore.
In Flutter, you can do it through a Platform channel Like this

Flutter Part:-

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('rateApp');   // initialize
```

onTap:     `platform.invokeMethod('urls', {'android_id': 'com.xyz'}),`

Now Android Native Part(Java):

```
private static final String RATEAPP = "rateApp";  // initialize variable
```

// Now in ConfigureFlutterEngine funtion:

```
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), RATEAPP)
            .setMethodCallHandler(
                    (call, result) -> {               
                        if (call.method.equals("urls") && call.hasArgument("android_id")) {
                            String id = call.argument("android_id").toString();
                          
                            try {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("$uri" + id)));
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + id)));
                            }
                            result.success("Done");
                        } else {
                            result.notImplemented();
                        }
                    }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested. This should work fine.

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val onOpenPlayStore: () -> Unit = {
    try {
        LOG.d(tag, "onOpenPlayStore ${context.packageName}")
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=${context.packageName}"))
        startActivity(context, intent, null)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${context.packageName}"))
        startActivity(context, intent, null)
    }
}
```