# Open google play app on my phone from an a href html tag on a website

Tags: android, html

I have an 
`<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.livewallpaper.medieval.castle.free">` 
on a webpage that takes to an app on googleplay.

Is there a way that a link in html opens the app of googleplay on my phone, not the webpage of googleplay.

I open the page on my android device, but it send me to the webpage not the option to open on the app of the phone.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open the google play store directly from my android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)

Comment: NOT duplicate. OP is asking how to open google play with html code not android code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
market://details?id=com.livewallpaper.medieval.castle.free
```