# Android InApp Purchase from another App

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have question in my mind, can i purchase different apps from one app only.For Example there is one app that contains all the my apps that is available to purchase in google play store.When will i select one of the app that it will be purchased and installed like different app in device.

Comment: Since they are still stand-alone apps, you can instead redirect them to your app in Play Store ([like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070/2821954)). As for your question, I doubt you can buy apps inside another app.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for your quick reply.It is very useful for me. I have another question that if user can go directly to Play Store than how can i do Inapp purchase? Also user can see all other my apps so it can be directly downloadable from Play Store instead of using my single app that list the all other apps.

Comment: I don't find the reason why you don't want your apps to be downloadable/purchasable from outside of your app. Perhaps you can elaborate more why you want to do this. As for in-app purchase, I don't think what you want is considered as IAP. I'm not an expert in this field though, so I might be wrong too.

Comment: @AndrewT. Because i think to download my all apps from my single app and IAP considered because i wants all my apps have some price.

Comment: You can also set price for your apps individually provided you have Google Wallet Merchant Account (IAP service also need this too). As for why it is not recommended to use IAP service to buy apps, one of the reason is because there is no possibility to refund.