# How to display the list of app stores installed on Android device?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I have a couple of app stores installed on my Android device, like `Play Store`(default), `Amazon App Store`, `Aptoide`, etc. Can someone tell me the intent that is needed to display the list of all those app stores?
When the user clicks on a link I want him to give the option to select the app store through which the app is to be downloaded. I am unable to find the intent action that would help me do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070

Comment: @Sreekanthss The solution in the link that you posted above, you need to know the package name and I am afraid it will directly launch the play store. My requirement is that I don't have the package name, I just need to display the app store list.

Comment: yes i understand your req  from question itself i am giving a hint of intent action only, i feel it is not a easy job to find the app stores in a device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my own question. I used the following piece of code to display the app stores installed on the device.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?"));
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
            ArrayList<String> storePacakgeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
                storePacakgeNames.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
            }
        }
```