# Redirect User to Play store From Android App

Tags: android, google-play

Hello Friends i am  developing an app , i had an requirement to redirect user to play store from my app , i searched a lot but no success .. code is below

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v_arg) {
            try {
                        Intent viewIntent =
                        new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                        Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adeebhat.rabbitsvilla/"));
                        startActivity(viewIntent);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to Connect Try Again...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v_arg) {
            try {
                        Intent viewIntent =
                        new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.adeebhat.rabbitsvilla/"));
                        startActivity(viewIntent);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to Connect Try Again...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. Did you got any error ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)

Answer (score 36):

More sophisticated way:

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // package name of the app
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

Comment: Just be careful when you are using `applicationIdSuffix` in different `buildTypes` or this will fail when you build in a non-production build because the packageName will be different than what you have on Google Play store. One package might be something like `com.youpackage.debug` and the release one something like `com.youpackage`.

Answer (score 14):

You just need to remove character `"/"` from the url

So will be

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adeebhat.rabbitsvilla/
```

to

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adeebhat.rabbitsvilla
```

So finally

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v_arg) {
        try {
                    Intent viewIntent =
                    new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adeebhat.rabbitsvilla"));
                    startActivity(viewIntent);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to Connect Try Again...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Remove slash from url. You have added extra slash after package name.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adeebhat.rabbitsvilla/
```

It should be

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adeebhat.rabbitsvilla
```

---

Both uri should be

```
Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adeebhat.rabbitsvilla")); // Removed slash
```

and

```
Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.adeebhat.rabbitsvilla")); // Removed slash
```