# Android: set dependency between two apps

Tags: android, aidl

I want to create an app which uses an aidl interface of another app. I was wondering if there is the possibility to make the other app automatically downloaded when the user install my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98

Basically, you cannot directly install the other app, only launch the thing that actually can install it. You would have to include the other apk inside of yours (in your assets folder perhaps), but if it's not your apk, then that's probably not a good idea unless you have the original author's permission.

If that other apk is published on Google Play, you could use PackageManager to check for the presence of the package name of that apk on the device. If you don't find it, invite the user to download the other app from Google Play using an Intent. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070/1207921) shows you how to open Google Play to a specific app.