# Launching Playstore with different parameter

Tags: android, google-play

I want to launch playstore from my application with different parameter.
Below are the list of things which I want to do from my application.

```
Show top free Games in playstore
Show Playstore categories
Show top paid apps in playstore ... etc etc
```

Is there a way I can do this? I have tried looking for it but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are many unofficial api's to retrieve playstore data.
 First one [This you can use in server side also](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)

Another  [for searching top apps](https://42matters.com/api/lookup)

Hope you will get the solution for your problem in one of the link

Comment: Can i do it without using any third party app? Does google or playstore provide any such thing?

Comment: Check out this link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for first and third. Only for second I did not find solution.
Below is the link. Need to start intent by setting data provided in link.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningPublisher