# How to install applications programatically from play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I want to install app from play store on button click event,and after user click button manage status of downloading.
Suppose i want to download facebook  from my app on a button click then, on a button click it should install on my device and i can get status of app is downloading/installing/pause/cancelled downloading.

Is this possible?
Please provide your idea for this.
Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

i found below code to check download event broadcast -

```
<receiver android:name="com.test.MyReceiver" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and i have broadcast receiver -

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    String referrerString = data.getString("referrer");

    Toast.makeText(context, "downloading....."+referrerString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

but my broadcast receiver is never got called.

for downloading app on button click if using below link -

```
http://market.android.com/details?id=your.application.package.name&referrer=my_referrer_finally_works_fine
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Not sure what else to say.

Comment: this is possible,because there are some app on play store which are doing same thing that i want.but i dont have any idea how they are doing.

Comment: @rb16 could you indicate such apps? I haven't met ones

Comment: sure,check this app -https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ayet.cashpirate

Answer (score 0):

You can't download an app from the play store.

You can show the user the play store app with the correct app page, so they can download, see [How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)

Comment: Thanks for you reply,can i get downloading status of app.if user click install button then when it install completely can i get a alert or notification.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver.html is what you are looking for.

Comment: i have try this receiver but my broadcast receiver not called.