# Android WebView : Why I can not able to redirect to play store from WebView?

Tags: android, webview, uiwebview, android-webview, webviewclient

I am trying to pass url to webview that should redirect to play store but Its not working.

What I tried :

```
String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matchify";
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

but its loading only inside the webview, how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use Intent instead ...

Comment: Thats fine. Is it possible from webview to play store?

Answer (score 1):

To open your app's / any other app's page on play store app use :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackName)));
```

Where appPackName is:

```
 String appPackName = getPackageName();
```

Play Store app has Intent Filter that will listen to the intent and launch the uri (since it is starting with market:// it will open Play Store. ) If you want to open in browser use uri argument :

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackName
```

Helpful link : [How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)