# redirecting the app to playstore url not working

Tags: android, servlets

Am working on android app on  which am inserting data to the database.if i get the result "Ok" from server then i want to redirect it to the playstore url .but when am hitting the url on browser its working fine but when am working with android device its not redirecting to the specified url.
here is my server code :

```
frmRefer.insertReferId(refer);
responseStr.setStatus(ServerResponse.STATUS.OK);
responseStr.setData(refer);
String serialId=responseStr.getData().getSerialId();
response.sendRedirect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=PACKAGE NAME&referrer=utm_source=admob&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term="+referId+"&utm_campaign=""&anid=admob");
session.commit();
```

Comment: your request URL are not working on Browser as well.

Comment: why you are not using 
    
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("your link")));

Comment: i dont want to do this on client side i want to do this by server

Comment: i want this from server side bacause i want to refer my app.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.app.url"));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
    Intent playStoreAppIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    try {
        startActivity(playStoreAppIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

      Intent playStoreWebIntent= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      playStoreWebIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<your project package name>"));//YOUR APP URL
      startActivity(playStoreWebIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String appPackageName = getPackageName();
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                        + appPackageName)));
    }
```

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)