# how to open playstore from a link in a post

Tags: android, facebook

I have an android app in which user can share stuff on facebook. The post will appear in the user's friend list. The post contains a link and what i want to implement is to open my app in playstore(and not in the browser) when the link is tapped, so that a user can download it.

Any pointer on how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe using this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how to structure the shared post on facebook so that when the user clicks it from facebook app it opens playstore. The post you mentioned explains how to do that from your own app.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks

Answer (score 0):

Usually android phones recognise play-store links and prompt users to decide where they want to open the link. Maybe you have set your device to open playstore links in your browser by default?

Answer (score 0):

Just place a link in format

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.bundleid
```

And most android smartphones will open this link in playstore rather than in browser.