# How to pop up 'new update available' dialogue, when user starts my app(android)

Tags: android, notifications, andengine, dialog

I made a game using AndEngine and I have made different updates three times and uploaded in google play store. I see that Google does provide a update notifications, but most of the people don't read the 'available updates' notification Google provides.

So When the users start my app, I want it to pop up a dialogue such as "A new version is available. Do you want to update?" and upon clicking the 'yes' button, it will link to the google market of my app.

Is there any way I could implement such device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this algorithm

1. launch app
2. check version from manifest
3. check version from a server (somewhere on the internet where you can update the version name/code manually when you release a new update)
4. compare the local and remote versions. If not equal [launch a URL to your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application).

Comment: wooo that sounds pretty smart! I will try it out thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a google api for that. The best way you can do it is to share a simple one line file with latest app version somewhere on the internet.
For example:
1. share a config file with content "1.0" which is a latest version of the app.
You can use google docs for that for example.
2. when your app start you read that file and compare the version there with your app version. If the version in the file is larger you show a dialog for the user.