# Phonegap config.xml - the unexplained intents

Tags: cordova

The [Phonegap/Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref/index.html) by and large does a great job of explaining the purpose of the various intents and other bits in the config.xml file.  However, I have been unable to establish the meaning/use of the following

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to explain what they are meant to do.

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I also couldn't find documentation for it!

Answer (score 12):

From the [whitelist plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist):

> **Intent Whitelist**
>
> Controls which URLs the app is allowed to ask the system to open. By
>   default, no external URLs are allowed.
>
> On Android, this equates to sending an intent of type BROWSEABLE.
>
> This whitelist does not apply to plugins, only hyperlinks and calls to
>   window.open().

Basically, it is what types urls are allowed to be opened with window.open(), so in your example:

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

the app would be able to open the Android Play Store and App store on iOS.  The links (market:*) will allow links to other apps in the play store (see Stack overflow question [How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)), and the (itms:*) allows links to apps in the itunes App Store.  This is probably required if you using any advertising plugin that redirects users to install apps.  These url schemes are pre-registered in Andriod and iOS by Google and Apple respectively.

Comment: Yes but what do market:, itms: etc actually do?  I can see what sms: does, or what tel: does but market etc is not at all clear.

Comment: Market allows opening of an app's page in the google play store (it used to be called the Android Market), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application .  itms allows opening of ios app pages in the itunes app store.

Comment: thanks . write that up as an answer and I will accept + upvote it.