# why my app stops working

Tags: android

could anyone please help me , why I cannot run this simple app , it was on Udemy tutorials , I have checked many times , exactly like it is in the tutorial

```
    package com.example.hp250.actions;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void OpenApp(View view) {

    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.soundcloud.android"));
    startActivity(intent);


  }
}
```

log cat :

```
02-29 06:56:17.774 4886-4886/com.example.hp250.actions I/art: Not       late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-29 06:56:17.775 4886-4886/com.example.hp250.actions I/art: Late-enabling JIT
02-29 06:56:17.777 4886-4886/com.example.hp250.actions I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
02-29 06:56:17.843 4886-4886/com.example.hp250.actions W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hp250.actions-1/lib/x86
02-29 06:56:18.013 4886-4910/com.example.hp250.actions D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-29 06:56:18.056 4886-4910/com.example.hp250.actions I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-29 06:56:18.190 4886-4910/com.example.hp250.actions W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-29 06:56:18.190 4886-4910/com.example.hp250.actions W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7607e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-29 06:56:20.394 4886-4886/com.example.hp250.actions D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-29 06:56:20.395 4886-4886/com.example.hp250.actions E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.hp250.actions, PID: 4886
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                          Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.soundcloud.android }
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1798)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
                                                                             at com.example.hp250.actions.MainActivity.OpenApp(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
02-29 06:56:22.922 4886-4886/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4886 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you add the logs from the logcat?

Comment: 02-29 06:56:20.395 4886-4886/com.example.hp250.actions E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.hp250.actions, PID: 4886
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)

Comment: Please post the FULL logcat into your original question, not as a comment.

Comment: layout file has only one button that has onclick attribute="openapp"

Comment: Try this in your `OpenApp` method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070/4350275

Comment: Perark Sola ... many thanks , it is actually works now , any clarifications fo that

Answer (score 3):

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.soundcloud.android }
```

You are running your app on a device or emulator that lacks the Play Store or any other activity that handles `market://details` `Uri` values for `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: how can i rectify this plz , knowing that i already ran another application on the same AVD "geo: longitude &latitude" there was no problem

Comment: @ZahraaFatma: The fact that you have a map application does not mean that you have the Play Store. Use a device that has the Play Store or something else that responds to that `Uri`. Or, do not use that `Uri`.