# How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application using Nativescript

Tags: google-play, nativescript

I'm new to both Android and Native Script. How do I open the Google Play Store inside my android app using Native Script. I've tried using web view and it works fine but I would like to open the Google Play Store using the Google Play Store app in the device.

Comment: So far I've tried using web view and passing URL for Google Play Store. Just a simple webview with the URL of Google Play Store as source. Also, I ave used this link for reference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application but most of it are not supported by Native Script and lack documentations for it.

Comment: It may help to add some details of what you've tried to the original question. You can edit the question and add more whenever you need to.

Answer (score -1):

Add permission application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Add code into oncreate method

```
String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps";
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Jan Michael try this answer.