# Open app installation page in AppStore or PlayStore

Tags: google-play, app-store, codenameone

I have a paid app in PlayStore (android) and AppStore (iOS). I'm developing a free app which have similar functions as the paid app but with ads banner at bottom and a time limitation when playing. In this free app, there is a button to allow user upgrade/install the paid app, when user click on this button, the app page on PlayStore will be displayed if the free app is playing on an Android device. Otherwise, the app page on the AppStore will be displayed (the free app is playing on an iOS device). How can I do this in CodenameOne?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use:

```
Display.getInstance().execute(url);
```

For Android see here how to build the url:
[How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)

For iOS see here how to build the url:
[How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)