# open app store from webview link

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I have a webview which displays an animated image advertisement which when clicked should open a link to the play store. When I click the image it opens the link in the webview so it gives an error message trying to display a play store page. 
Is there a way to get the link and open the play store externally and not within the webview

Comment: Possibly duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application

Comment: can you post the url when you click on the images in the webview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the `WebViewClient` and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.
Set the custom webview client to your webView.
In method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` check if the `url` is the Google play link, then return true (may be you need to start the browser intent by yourself).

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem

Try changing the url from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.package.name to market://details?id=com.your.package.name

worked for me