# Opening the app's page in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

This question had been asked at least a couple times, and the answer is always the same, along the lines of

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName())));`

The problem is, it doesn't work for me. It opens the main Google Play page, not my app's page. My app is indeed on Google Play, had been for 4 years. Interestingly, this code did work a couple years ago when I first written it but now it doesn't.

Comment: can you show getPackageName() - the rest looks good

Comment: May be your getPakageName is returning null or you might have changed the package of your development app.

Comment: @MohammedAtif: no. I have now hard-coded the package name as defined by the `package` directive at the top of the .java file. And I never changed the package name. I've successfully published an update just a few days ago, think it wouldn't let me if package name didn't match.

Comment: yes the problem must be with your package name, this is working with my package name.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, what exactly is the behaviour you are observing?

Comment: @Tony: Google Play opens at the initial screen. Same as if I launch it via the home screen shortcut.

Comment: Try this once, `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appPackageName` in your browser

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application?rq=1

Comment: @MohammedAtif: same thing.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, if you dont mind, can you tell the package name