# Launch Google play store from Kivy app

Tags: python, google-play, kivy, python-webbrowser

I want to create a button in my app (using Kivy) which when pressed opens a particular app page in Google play store.

Request some guidance to achieve this.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)

Comment: @Evgeniy Mishustin thank you. But as I mentioned, I am using Kivy to build my app. How can I implement this java code in Kivy?

Comment: Simply launch that Intent on button click. Do you know how to launch Intents in Kivy?

Comment: No. Can you please tell me how to launch intents in Kivy?

Comment: @VijaykumarWalikar look [here](https://github.com/tito/2048/blob/master/gs_android.py), it's tito's version of 2048, which handles even scoreboard and achievements. I think it's the only file that has something with android directly, but feel free to search more. Of course, to access android classes you'll need [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius).

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr thank you. I had a look at it and since I don't know much of Java I couldn't follow entire thing. However it was an useful link which I think I can use it in future. Now coming to the problem, I solved it by just launching `webbrowser.open("market://details?id=your.awesome.app")` on button click. This open the app of interest directly in Play store app.