# how to open the Google Play account page on programmatically with startActivity

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am trying to open the Google Play Store Account page in my own app in order to users can confirm their payment method or order history.

[image]

How can I do it? Please help me.
I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)

Comment: Thank you. but my problem is difference from that. I am going to open Google Account page. Not application page on Play Store.

Comment: I used this method to open playstore `private void openPlaystore(Context context) {
        final Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
        try {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Coudn't find PlayStore on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/account")));
```