# Android IntentFilter Custom Scheme [ONLY custom scheme] not opening the app

Tags: android, intentfilter, custom-scheme-url

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "myscheme://" -->
      <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
      <data android:pathPattern="/.*"></data>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have added the above code in the `manifest.xml` and am trying to open `myscheme` from the emulator's browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain how did you tried it ?

Comment: Opened the browser from the emulator. Typed `myscheme` or `myscheme://`. Expected the app to open.

Comment: I don't think chrome will open external apps like this even it you did it correctly. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840518/open-my-app-from-url-scheme-in-android)