# Is it possible to hide one android app inside another?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I want to use google translate offline lang.packs. But it has to be a diff. app with a diff. icon.

My app has to work completely offline. Google translate does work offline if the packs are on the phone. But the packs are not available as standalone or in API format!
**I do know from another answer that the lang packs and the neural model is a major value of the company**. So they dont want to give it away for free to devs as API.

Training my own neural model with libs like TensorFlow is daunting task. I want to reuse existing libraries\apps

Comment: Whats your Purpose of Hiding the App..?

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM, it's freelance gig, and a bank wants it

Comment: Check apertium http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Main_Page . They have an android app also which is also open source. I don't think you can use google data though. http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Apertium_Android

Comment: what is your actual question? Hiding stuff can be considered malicious

Comment: @ERJAN Are you trying to install Google Translate app along with Your Application..??

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM, never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Google Play Privacy Policy](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/) Hiding an App within another App Without User's Knowledge is Considered as a Malicious Behavior.

> The following are explicitly prohibited:
>
> - Viruses, trojan horses, malware, spyware or any other malicious
>     software. Apps that link to or facilitate the distribution or
>     installation of malicious software.
> - Apps or SDKs that download executable code, such as dex files or
>     native code, from a source other than Google Play.
> - Apps that introduce or exploit security vulnerabilities.
> - Apps that steal a user’s authentication information (such as
>     usernames or passwords) or that mimic other apps or websites to trick
>     users into disclosing personal or authentication information.
> - Apps that install other apps on a device without the user’s prior
>     consent.
> - Apps designed to secretly collect device usage, such as commercial
>     spyware apps.

Here are my Suggestions.

**Suggestion 1 :** Recommended Way

- Check Weather the Required Applications are  Installed / Not in User Mobile

  ```
      try {                          
          context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
          return true;  //Application Installed
      }
      catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
          return false; //Application Not Installed
      }
  ```
- If not Redirect them to the PlayStore  [(Originally Answered Here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070/5740760)

  > ```
  >  final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName()
  >  from Context or Activity object try {
  >      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName))); } catch
  >  (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
  >      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
  >  appPackageName))); }
  > ```

**Suggestion 2 :** If You wish to Distribute the Application offline(Not through PlayStore) Then

- Append the Required Apk Files in Assets folder of the Main Application
- Do the same Check Like in **Suggestion 1**. But Instead of Redirecting to PlayStore, Launch the Package Installer for the Apk in Assets Folder.

I have done a [Demo Project](https://github.com/gotoark/Android/tree/master/ApkInstallerDemo/app/src/main/java/arkthepro/apkinstallerdemo) for this scenario . Please Check it  for More Reference

Comment: because u bothered to answer my question.. i flag it as helpful and green mark! thank u

Comment: Thanks, @ERJAN. You made me to do some useful R&D on this and i also Learned a lot because of Your Question ;)