# Installing multiple apk file by installing one

Tags: android

I am trying to create a launcher app that has multiple apps incorporated in it. Currently I am able to launch other apps from my launcher but I have to install those apps manually. What I need is, once I install the launcher app all other apps that need to be added in the launcher app should be installed by the launcher app.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since its not possible, you best way is to render the icons of your apps, and make them clickable. Once you click on the button take the user to the app link. Here is a sample for going to an app link in play store: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48834205/2880778

Comment: We are developing this for a custom tablet. so we wont be uploading this in playstore.We will be making this a system app of the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Android System Does not allowed you to do that , because every time when app is being installed it opens system dialog to install app like below image :

[image]

So ,

> it impossible to install multiple app through single app without user
>   attention.

Yes , you can launch different apps from your app , but installing them indirectly is not possible , due to security purpose .

Comment: How to do it by notifying the user?

Comment: @EbyCloudins , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Comment: post a new question with error what you are getting .