# How can i show dialog to my application on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have free version application with Ads. I want to add a button that, when clicked, will pop up such a dialog with my paid application without Ads. 
[screen dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek3Q6.jpg)
Can this be implemented?

Comment: Why don't you make an implicit intent to your app's paid version on Google Play?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is possible. You should consider using an implicit intent to redirect the user to the Google Play application.

Check this out: [How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)