# Flutter Open AppStore/PlayStore URL

Tags: flutter

How can I open a specific URL of the PlayStore/AppStore with flutter on Android and IOS, depending on which smartphone it is executed?
I mean I want to open the application and **not a browser** or something like this.

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application) I found some native way for **android** but how can I do this with flutter?

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

If there is currently no way to do this, it would be a nice feature to implement for the plugin [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher).

Comment: Note that you can get your app's package name in pure Dart code, without writing any Java, by using the [flutter_android](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_android) plugin's [`Context.packageName`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/flutter_android/latest/android_content/Context/packageName.html) getter.

Answer (score 76):

You can use [url_luncher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) and open the url based on the platform like this:

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
  final appId = Platform.isAndroid ? 'YOUR_ANDROID_PACKAGE_ID' : 'YOUR_IOS_APP_ID';
  final url = Uri.parse(
    Platform.isAndroid
        ? "market://details?id=$appId"
        : "https://apps.apple.com/app/id$appId",
  );
  launchUrl(
    url,
    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
  );
}
```

**Note**

- You can get your iOS app id from `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=YOUR_BUNDLE_ID` then look for `trackId`
- This wont work on iOS simulators as they don't have an app store
- Setting the `mode` to `LaunchMode.externalApplication` will *prevent* the safari flash for a second

Comment: please make an example for YOUR_BUNDLE_ID for 1 app on apple store .

Comment: YOUR_BUNDLE_ID = Bundle Identifier thats mean packange name  ??? or how ??? 


```{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}```

Comment: Here is an example with the apple pages app https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.apple.Pages

Comment: You will have set a bundle id for your iOS app so use that, it will be in your signing and capabilities section something like `com.companyname.appname`

Comment: But its return file txt right ? Why not a json ? So in flutter we need to handle the download file and casting or read the inside file content right ?

Comment: ah my bad , we can pass content type and call it with `curl` to test , not direct by `browser access` , thankyou sir but i still didnt find the result , i only work with `http://itunes.apple.com/search?media=software&country=id&term=app%20name` i cant search my package name its just result resultCount 0. with  `itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.apple.Pages`, did you know why ? can you please real example ?

Comment: You don't need to handle this in Flutter, this is just to get your iOS app id, it is not dynamic. Once you have the value you can replace `YOUR_IOS_APP_ID` in the code example with the id you have retrieved

Comment: you can get app id from apple marketing tools https://tools.applemediaservices.com/

Answer (score 54):

You can use this [Library](https://github.com/Purus/launch_review),

Basically, To use this plugin, add `launch_review` as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.

```
launch_review: ^1.0.1
```

To use :

```
 import 'package:launch_review/launch_review.dart';
```

Then invoke the static launch method of LaunchReview anywhere in your Dart code. If no arguments are provided, it will consider the current package.

```
LaunchReview.launch();
```

To open the App Store page for any other applications, you can pass the app Id.

```
LaunchReview.launch(androidAppId: <package name>,
                iOSAppId: <ios app id>);
```

Comment: Great thank you. :) I will try to implement it later .

Comment: Not using flutter for more than 10 months. Please consider adding a issue in Github repo of library. Maintainers may reply to you there itself.

Comment: now it has `writeReview` option, so `LaunchReview.launch(writeReview: false);`

Comment: For future users, for iOS this no longer works unless you specify the iosAppId explicitly.

Comment: make sure you pass the package name to whatever plugin you use, I was passing an empty string.

Answer (score 11):

**You can do something similar in flutter:**

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

try {
  launch("market://details?id=" + appPackageName);
} on PlatformException catch(e) {
    launch("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);        
} finally {
  launch("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);        
}
```

The exception/catch does not seem to work for some reason so adding 'finally'  did the trick, finally :)

Comment: You cannot catch an exception that occurs in a function/method returning `Future` unless you put `await` when you call it.

Comment: ahhh I see, but how come the 'finally' part gets executed?

Comment: The `finally` block is executed regardless of whether an exception occurred of not. I suspect that your code tries to open the store twice.

Comment: hmm... i don't see that behavior... I'll test again.

Comment: On flutter web, on Chrome Mobile the first method does not work, hence it opens the play store on the ugly web site.

Comment: What about app store ? that is only for anrdoid, how to open app store

Comment: You don't need `try/catch`, You can use `if/else` with the `canLaunch()` method of `url_launcher` package.

Comment: After using it for a while, I've realized that it opens the stock store (App Gallery) instead of Google Play on Huawei phones. To learn more, look here: https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app

Answer (score 10):

This is like the most popular answer to this question, but without the need of saying the Android package. In addition, this solution doesn't show a toast on Android saying "Please Rate Application".

It depends on [open_store](https://pub.dev/packages/open_store) and [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus).

```dart
const appStoreId = "1234567890"; // Your app's App Store ID
final packageName = (await PackageInfo.fromPlatform()).packageName;

OpenStore.instance.open(
  androidAppBundleId: packageName,
  appStoreId: appStoreId,
);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package for opening the appstore/playstore as follows :

```
      _launchURL(String url) async {
         if (await canLaunch(url)) {
             await launch(url);
         } 
         else {
             throw 'Could not launch $url';
         }
       }
```

Comment: using this as a uri works "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/appname/id1485117463" but first safari shows up for a second or two then the safari itself redirects it to the actual app :D

Answer (score 4):

You can use this plug in. [here](https://pub.dev/packages/open_appstore#-readme-tab-)

Super simple.
To use this pulg in, just write the package name (app id) on your dart code like this.

```
OpenAppstore.launch(androidAppId: "com.facebook.katana&hl=ko", iOSAppId: "284882215")
```

Comment: How do I find my iOSAppId? Struggling to locate this

Comment: It doesn't support Sound Null Safety :·( In addition, Android package name could be automatically read from the app build itself...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [store_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/store_launcher)

Example

```dart
StoreLauncher.openWithStore(appId);
```

Comment: It doesn't support Sound Null Safety :·( In addition, Android package name could be automatically read from the app build itself...

Answer (score 0):

Function to open the App Store or Play Store URL in yo flutter app

```
Future<void> _openStore() async {
String packageName = 'put your_package_name';
String appStoreUrl = 'https://apps.apple.com/app/$packageName';
String playStoreUrl = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageName';

if (await canLaunch(appStoreUrl) && !Platform.isAndroid) {
  await launch(appStoreUrl);
} else if (await canLaunch(playStoreUrl) && Platform.isAndroid) {
  await launch(playStoreUrl);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch store';
}
```

}