# Redirect to playstore/appstore if the app is not install

Tags: flutter, next.js

I am working in a project that is build with next.js. I have a mobile app for that project that is build with flutter. Now I want to redirect user to the appstore or playstore if the app is not installed in user phone. I can show popup dialogue for choosing if user wants to continue with the app or with the browser when the app is installed, I want to show same popup dialogue if the app is not installed, in this case when user choose the app then it will redirect to the store. how can I redirect user to appstore or playstore if the app is not installed.

Comment: check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685112/flutter-open-appstore-playstore-url?rq=1