# App Share button in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play, android-studio-3.0, appstore-approval, share-button

I want to Distribute my App to the App store but i want to add a Share button with a Link, so that when a user clicks the link, it should open the App in the App store...

This is the **Version 1.0** of my App.

How can i get a link for my **App** before it is completely visible to users???

Comment: `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME` (take the package name from the manifest) (check the docs https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

Your app has a package name (also called an application id). For example, for Gmail it is `com.google.android.gm`.

As described at the [Marketing Guidelines for Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play)
the link is always `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>` ie for gmail it would be `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped.

Comment: In StackOverflow, if an answer helps it is normally good to vote it up, or mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your app in play store in "Closed Beta". Details are [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213).

Once you've created your beta, you will see in "App Releases" --> "Beta" --> "Manage" a place where the opt-in URL in shown.

You can share the opt-in url and your users will be directed to a page explaining what it means to become a beta tester and it will also have a link to your beta version of the app.

Comment: Lefteris. Thanks But... what i really am asking is to get only the Link which will be used on Button click.

Comment: I understand that you want the link to work ** before your app is completely visible to users **. In this case it will need to be a testing version (i.e. open/closed beta) and you need to do what I mentioned above. You can use what Mehdi B shared, in order to distribute it before Play Store has been updated with your app, but once it is updated (after a few hours from publishing) it will be visible to everyone.

Comment: Thanks Lefteris... i have understood now. But will i have to release the beta when i get the Link? or i will have to upload another Apk in the Production Release?