# Link to another apps from my android app

Tags: android, google-play, policy

The idea is to make a sponsored area on my app every link on this area will point to the app link on google playstore.

My question:

is this method is forbidden by Google Guidelines or will not cause my app suspension ?

Thanks

Comment: opening other app's pages in google play is just fine

Comment: Thank you Vladyslav

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)

Comment: shkschneider I'm not asking for how to achieve it I alreadyy know thank you, but I asked for the policy with google playstore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening other apps on playstore is perfectly fine since there is a tutorial to it in the official documentation https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#java

Therefore it is not forbidden and permited by google to do this.