# Implement Rate Us and More Apps link for Huawei App Gallery

Tags: android, google-play, huawei-mobile-services

How can i implement Rate Us and More Apps in Unity for Huawei app gallery? I use this way for Google Play Store but i'm unable to find for Huawei.

Rate Us: Application.OpenURL ("market://details?id=package of game");

More Apps : Application.OpenURL ("market://search?q=pub:Turbo Game Studios");

Please help.

Comment: You need to open the Huawei App Gallery from code? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58343131/1876355 . Try `"appmarket://details?id=com.my.app"`

Comment: @pierre Thanks for your reply. I have implemented the "Rate US" as you guided. But what should i do for "More Apps" or to open developer account/open more by this developer programmatically ?

Comment: You can't - Huawei haven't implemented their intents to be so complicated.... Yet of course - Shows you your app and that is it. Maybe later they will catch up to Google's finer attention to detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Huawei App Gallery** uses its own scheme `appmarket://`

- Scheme: `appmarket://`
- Package: `com.huawei.appmarket`

vs. **Google Play Store**:

- Scheme: `market://`
- Package: `com.android.vending`

The functionality differs at this time of writing, *HAG* only supports basic app opening so you can only send an intent `Uri` like the following:

```
"appmarket://details?id=package.of.game"
```

Huawei will probably-eventually catch up with more functionalities like Google through intents as to allow other types of requests from external apps.

But as for now, only open your app package, that is it.

If you have the app gallery installed, and can manage to see all the apps from the developer, you can try and share it to find the link, and open that link in the users' browser, for instance (This is just an App link):

https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/marketshare/app/C100864605

### **Update**

---

You can now open your app in Huawei App Gallery the same way as for Google, you will then choose between the two stores if you have both installed:

Works for all stores:

```
market://details?id=com.mypackage.name
```

Works for app gallery only:

```
appmarket://details?id=com.mypackage.name

market://com.huawei.appmarket.applink?appId=C100864605
```

Comment: Note: This is not working as expected in Huawei P10 Pro. When using 'markets://', the AppGallery is opened, instead of Google Play Store.

Comment: @HX_unbanned market**s** or market ? Thanks for letting know - This was just a demonstration to show the differences between Google Play scheme and App Gallery scheme. If you want to ensure you open the correct store, look at my answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58343131/1876355](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58343131/1876355)

Comment: @Pierre , yes, `market` , it was my typo. Sorry. Anyhow - surely happy to share! ;)

Comment: It seems Huawei App Gallery can now open the details page with the same URI that works for Google Play: "market://details?id=<applicationId>" 
I tried it out on AppGallery v11.1.2.304 with an applicationId that exists on both stores: adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "market://details?id=busu.blackscreenbatterysaver"

Answer (score 1):

App rating on HUAWEI AppGallery can be implemented by redirecting to the app details page, on which the app rating function is provided.

Answer (score 0):

From Huawei's [documentation](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0203478067208130016) :

Method 1：by app ID

```
public void launchAppDetailsPage1() {
     Intent intent = new Intent("com.huawei.appmarket.appmarket.intent.action.AppDetail.withid");
     intent.setPackage("com.huawei.appmarket");
     intent.putExtra("appId", "C100170981");
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

Method 2：by package name

```
public void launchAppDetailsPage2() {
     Intent intent = new Intent("com.huawei.appmarket.intent.action.AppDetail");
     intent.setPackage("com.huawei.appmarket");
     intent.putExtra("APP_PACKAGENAME", "com.huawei.browser");
     startActivity(intent);
}
```