# How to open the Huawei AppGallery store with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

How do I open the Huawei AppGallery that points to a specific app directly?
I know that is possibile to do it natively in Android, but I need to do it with plain Javascript for a Cordova application

Comment: You can use JavaScript code to directly open the Huawei AppGallery. Please kindly refer to the following two posts: [POST 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705612/how-to-open-the-huawei-appgallery-directly/58343131#58343131); [POST 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705612/how-to-open-the-huawei-appgallery-directly/60641091#60641091) Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following:

The typical link format of the application details page on Huawei AppGallery is: https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/appDetail?pkgName=**packagename**&channelId=**channelid**&referrer=**referrer**&detailType=0&calltype=AGDLINK

Parameter description:

**Packagename**: required, the package name to be popularized and applied, such as com.huawei.gamebox ..

**Channelid**: It is recommended to fill in. To improve the channel identification degree of data analysis, it is recommended to fill in the designated identification number for each channel. If it is not filled in, the system will automatically read the package name of the source media, but the package name cannot be obtained by jumping through the webpage or offline QR code.

**Referrer**: not required; if not, it will be blank by default. This parameter refers to the secondary channel number. When links are posted on multiple pages (scenes) of the same media, the specific location effect of the media can be identified by the secondary channel number.

DetailType=0&calltype=AGDLINK: basic parameter, which cannot be deleted.

for example: https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/appDetail?pkgName=com.huawei.gamebox&channelId=ceshi&referrer=01&detailType=0&calltype=AGDLINK

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest and easiest one would be running this simple link:
https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/ag/n/app/<YOUR_APP_ID>

No need `Packagename`, `Channelid` and stuffs like that and no need to config anything and the rest will handled by Huawei automatically.

How to get YOUR_APP_ID?

1. Go to [Huawei App Gallery](https://appgallery.huawei.com/#/Featured)
2. Search for your app (e.g. [WeChat](https://appgallery.huawei.com/#/search/wechat?1628141312994))
3. Copy the ID in the end of the link (e.g. https://appgallery.huawei.com/#/app/C5683)
4. In this case the APP_ID for WeChat would be `C5683`
5. So the Huawei app link for WeChat would be https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/ag/n/app/C5683

Hope this helps! Enjoy~