# Opening a dialog to install an app instead of Playstore

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I know that usually we are opening Playstore app for **Rate/Review App or Install app** using [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11753000/1318946).

But I want to open dialog directly to **recommend some apps to install directly** as below:

This screen is taken from [**Google Home**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app&hl=en_IN) app:

[image]

My questions:

- Is there any way to open dialog directly?
- Is it allow by Playstore open our other apps for user recommendations?

Comment: I want to open playstore with particular app only. I can make my own dialog but is there any way to display as per image?

Comment: ***"I want to open playstore with particular app only"*** what does this mean ? (as you say you can start playstore app with an intent, do you want some extra intent settings that launch the dialog ? {if they exist and are accessable}) . I'm still not clear about what you want, and what the problem is. If you are having problems writing a dialog that **looks like** that one, then yes you can. Are you trying to do a personal re-write of Playstore app or Google home ? Have you checked what source code Google Android have released (in the github)? Have you checked the docs ?

Comment: Thank you for long description. I have tried to find in many open source apps but didn't get succeed. I just want to put in my app for **more apps.** Hope you got my point.

Comment: @JonGoodwin I think OP wants to open same dialog by passing some extra field through intent into the playstore.

Comment: One simple solution would be to use the `<WebView>` in your dialog
[https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: @JonGoodwin Sorry, I didn't get what you are trying to say