# Unable to open google play store from android webview

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, android-webview, google-play-console

I am opening a url in android `webview` which is redirecting the user to google play store web page in android `webview` and play store page is showing **OPEN IN PLAY STORE APP**

[image]

and while clicking that button **rather then opining play store app** `webview` is redirecting to a web url which is **not found**.

[image]

Now i don't know why it is happening as in google chrome app same scenario is working fine. Please suggest the better solution.

Some code i have done :

```
   mWebView.loadUrl("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.org.npci.upiapp&hl=en") 

   mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, urlNewString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }
    });
```

Note: I am using this play store url just as an example.

Comment: Not sure if this will help but try setting Webchromeclient  `mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

Comment: @ManoharReddy  no its not working

Comment: Why not directly open your app on play store https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application ?

Comment: @ManoharReddy i have to open a web url in a `webview` and that page contains some buttons like download this app from google play store so i cant open the app on play store directly

Comment: I wouldn't use Google Play as an example. Google Play has specific intent features so if you navigate to it on Android it will open the Play Store app instead. Try with a different URL.

Comment: @NickFortescue i tried with different url's app store app is not opening through `webview`, please try it at your end and if something i am missing please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, but you must also inspect the URL and conditionally create an intent if it starts with the `intent://` scheme. We (the Android WebView team) have written a [sample application](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/tools/system_webview_shell/apk/src/org/chromium/webview_shell/WebViewBrowserActivity.java?l=693-735&rcl=d31e140abb984481993f34a9fdd2d47a7a093c0d) which does precisely this.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this data in the webview:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url != null && url.startsWith("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=putyourplaystoreid")) {
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. It was fine with code directly put, instead of with picture