# How open app chooser when user click on dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to use dynamic link (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) in my app. This tool has lots of advantages but I noticed that if the application is not installed, the system automatically redirects to the playstore without asking the user anything.
I would like the user to be able to choose to open the link in their browser rather than download the application

Is there a way to force the system to display the app chooser (playstore/web browser) when the user click on the dynamic link ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application

Comment: My question is not how to open app chooser from my app but how to configure dynamic-link so that the system asks the user before redirecting it to the play store to download the application

Comment: simple, check the app in your device, is it installed or not, if not installed then configure your link in market app like "market://details?id=<app_package_name>" and open the chooser with intent.