# "market://details?id=" + appPackageName opens the app not the playstore page

Tags: java, android

i asked a question on how should i open the playstore page using an app link on my app. i got an answer to use "market://details?id=" + appPackageName to open the play store app but instead of opening the playstore page its re opening my app. whats the fix?

```
enter code here

protected void Updateclick(View view) {
        String appPackageName="io.kodular.samithuaz.smartQ";
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));

}
```

Comment: First check your package is valid or not including case sensitive Character . For URI `market://details?id` to work you have to have Play Store app installed on device . Other wise you have to use a fallback . follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.You need to specify proper store URI for the different stores.
take reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20open,app%27s%20Google%20Play%20store%20pages.)

```
protected void Updateclick(View view) {
final String appPackageName = getPackageName();

try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
         Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i was using was an image click that why it didnt worked. when i used a button click it worked.

Comment: This is comment not answer