# why there is no option to navigate programatically to our app rating screen of google play store exactly in android like an iOS?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, apk, rating

We have the below option, but it is navigating to top of our app page only. I want to navigate programatically to write a review screen of my app exactly. This option is available in iOS.

**Android(Navigating only to the app screen playstore)**

```
val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName")
val goToAppRatingPageAction = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
startActivity(goToAppRatingPageAction)
```

**iOS(Navigating exactly to the rating screen in app store)**

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL("itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/\(appID)?action=write-review")
```

I have rate us option in my app, when we click on it, i have to navigate to write a review screen of my app in play store.

Comment: is your app released in playstore/appstore  first?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070/7758318

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking for this

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review

Android already provides it . You don't need to redirect user to outside of your app . You can provide smooth experience to user by integrating this But make sure you ask for rating after sometime

Comment: Yes, I come across this thing, it have some limitations like need to show 1 time in a month like that. Just, I wish to have a rate us option which links to my app rating screen of google play store.