# For in app purchases on Android, does the app have to be installed from Google Play?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

In order to use in app purchases on Android does the app have to be distributed via Google Play?  To clarify, there are two questions:

- If I create `com.my.app` and distribute it both via the Google Play store and via my own methods will apps installed either way be able to purchase in app purchases?
- If I create `com.my.app` and only distribute it via my own methods will people be able to make in app purchases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you distribute the same APK with the same signature inside and outside Google Play so the app purchase should works. App purchase only works for APK version equal or lower the Play store.

Remember that Google Play apk should be installed on phones to app purchase works.

Comment: So you're saying: **1)** I _do_ have to have the app in the Goole Play Store for in-app purchases to work outside fo the store, **2)** the APK version in the store has to be the same or _higher_ than the one I distribute manually and **3)** the Google Play APK has to be installed on the device as well?  What if the Google Play APK isn't, is there an API to detect that?  Thanks!

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551531/cannot-determine-whether-google-play-store-is-installed-or-not-on-android-device