# How to check that device has play store, and user has signed in using their google account

Tags: android, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot determine whether Google play store is installed or not on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551531/cannot-determine-whether-google-play-store-is-installed-or-not-on-android-device)

I would like to do two things:

1) Check that the device has Google Play installed (since it is not available on some devices such as HCL me tablet etc.)

2) If Google Play is installed, is it possible to tell whether the user is signed in with a Google account?

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, more an indication that the OP didn't search SO for an answer before just posting the first half of their question. Checking the account used is another matter though

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
[PackageManager.getPackageInfo][1]
```

with package: com.android.vending

```
Throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException if a package with the given name can not be found on the system.
```