# How to check if an android device has Google Play installed?

Tags: android

I am trying to check if the device has Google Play installed or not in my app, but seems there is no way to do that. I followed the post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551531/cannot-determine-whether-google-play-store-is-installed-or-not-on-android-device) but still doesn't work, always return true even i was testing with an emulator, it has com.android.vending installed. So am i checking the wrong package name? Any ideas for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you show us your code?

Comment: the code i am using is all from the link in my post.

`

private static final String GooglePlayStorePackageNameOld = "com.google.market";
private static final String GooglePlayStorePackageNameNew = "com.android.vending";

protected final boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName) {
    try {
        application.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Follow [Dcoumentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure) to check if the device has Google Play Service available.

In Short, simply:

```
// Getting status
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

// Showing status
if(status==ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
//Google Play Services are available
else{
//Google Play Services are not available
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I need to check Google Play Store, not Google Play Service.Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, found a way to check Google Play installed, here is the code:

```
public static boolean isPackageInstalled(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
       PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.android.vending", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
       String label = (String) info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm);
       app_installed = (!TextUtils.isEmpty(label) && label.startsWith("Google Play"));
    } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
       app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```